# Inserting values into sqlite tables in android device

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to Android and Java. I am creating an Android application in which I will be collecting data and also importing data from server to Android.

I wish to store the data imported into SQLite tables. So I created two tables as per my requirement. This tables should be created when ever app is opened and should be cleaned when ever the app is CLOSED not switched. For this I am dropping the tables in onOpen(), it is working fine in Emulator. I am able to see the values in `DDMS-Data`.

Now I am trying to implement it on android mobile and I am looking at data folder in `DDMS` for the device. But I don't see any tables. The folder remains empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes its restricted to view table inside data folder for Device as manufacturer by default have not given permission to view it.But your tables do exist inside your data folder.

You can check by opening it inside your app if you want to confirm. You can definitely drop your tables and it will get cleaned when ever the app is closed don't worry about it. You have to root your device to get permission , which will take away your device warranty.

Comment: Thanks Mohit. I have one more question. entry.open();
entry.createEntry(Point_Id, Polyline_Id,gpsTraces);
entry.close();
This is the piece of code I am trying to run every time I have an update, into sqlite table. But what I see is, when ever it runs it calls onOpen function which has drop tables. But what I need is to drop tables only when the app is closed. Can you sort me out please

Comment: how many activies are there in your app. You want to drop table when a particular activity is closed or when the whole app is closed. In that case i will need info regarding your app flow and activities.

Comment: Hi Mohit.I just had one activity running. Basically its a navigation app with google maps api. For now I am just clicking on back arrow button on my device to close the app. But I am not sure doing is so meant to close the app or does it still be running. I can provide you the outline of my code. I have few more question following this.

Comment: you can write all your code in onbackkeypressed function and at last call finish().

Answer (score 0):

You cant check Database table from Device by ddms utility. cause it wont be listed there, but you can check data by applying a select query, wherever you want to debug.

Comment: Hi jeet. Thanks for the reply. Where can I query to check it?

Comment: Create a method which read all the records from database tables. and call this method, after records insertion, deletion, or table creation.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices needs to be 'rooted' in order to be able to access the data folder. You can read more about this process on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29 However if you need it only to see your tables it's not recommended to do it.